# Private Bytes are increasing in C# application

Tags: c#, memory, private

I created an application to track currently Active Window on the screen. I am using Timer and subscribing its Elapsed event so it can process my code. I have set the timer Interval to 2 seconds.

As I run this application I see increase value of Private Bytes (reflecting in TaskManager) and it keeps on increasing.

After watching youtube videos I tried to set all possible objects to Null for proper disposal and also set used "Using" statement to reclaim memory from native objects.

```
class myservice
{

    public void Start()
    {
        Timer tActiveWin = new Timer();
        tActiveWin.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds;
        tActiveWin.Elapsed += TActiveWin_Elapsed;
        tActiveWin.AutoReset = true;
        tActiveWin.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void TActiveWin_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var win = new WindowEvents().GetActiveWindow();
        Console.WriteLine(win.activewindowtitle);
    }
}

class WindowEvents
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

    public JsonAppEvents.Activewindow GetActiveWindow()
    {
        Task<JsonAppEvents.Activewindow> activeWindow = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
                JsonAppEvents.Activewindow activeWin = new JsonAppEvents.Activewindow();

                IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

                int processID = 0;
                int threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processID);


            using (Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processID))
            {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(256);
                if (GetWindowText(hWnd, text, 256) > 0)
                {
                    text.ToString();
                }

                activeWin.activewindowfullpath = p.MainModule.FileName;
                activeWin.activewindowtitle = p.MainWindowTitle;
                activeWin.time = p.StartTime.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                activeWin.activewindowdescription = p.MainModule.ModuleName;

                p.Dispose();

                hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
                processID = 0;
                threadID = 0;
                text.Clear();
                text = null;

                return activeWin;
            }
        });


        return activeWindow.Result;

    }
}


class JsonAppEvents
{

    public class Activewindow
    {
        public string activewindowfullpath { get; set; }
        public string activewindowdescription { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public string activewindowtitle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After running the program I captured Private bytes as follows :

---

### PrivateBytes   Time

5,300 K       8:45 PM

5,800 K       8:46 PM

7,252 K       8:47 PM

7,260 K       8:49 PM

---

I am looking for some help on it so i can stabilise Private Bytes from getting increase and can trace it properly why is it happening? is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Try removing the `p.Dispose()` inside the using block. The using block will dispose of `p` properly, so a manual disposal is not needed.

Comment: I did it actually but it didn't make any impact on growth of Private Bytes.

Comment: Are you sure `Start` is only being called once?

Comment: Yes. even i am calling Start from Main().

Comment: Never use a 2 second timer to troubleshoot a possible memory leak.  You have to wait too long to see the sawtooth pattern of the garbage collector appear.  Run it as fast as it can.  And keep in mind that 7 MB is peanuts and not nearly enough to qualify as a leak, you haven't even filled up the gen #0 segment.

Answer (score 0):

You are dispatching tasks using the `Task.Factory.StartNew` which  may result in the creation of new threads. Each thread gets allocated memory which is why you see private bytes increase.
Use [ClrDbg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clrdbg/) to perform a memory diagnostic of your application

Comment: As you are saying Memory is allocated to each new thread, Is it the reason behind the growth of Private Bytes? But once a thread is finished with its job then it should reclaim its memory back, isn't it?

Comment: Those threads will be reused and cleanup by the thread pool when no longer used.

Comment: Sir, I waited around 4 hours and it kept growing.